# When should an AD Carry take Flash vs. Ghost?

Tags: league-of-legends

When I play an AD Carry in ranked, especially one with a gap closer ( Graves, Corki, Ez, Vayne), I like to choose ghost for the extra chasing power. I don't see the advantage that flash gives, besides the positioning, that makes it a more viable pick than ghost.

Is Flash ever the better choice?

Answer (score 2):

Flash is better in pretty much every way, especially for ADC playing bot

With ghost you do get the extra boost of chasing power but that is ALL you get.  If you get CC'd or ganked at all, which you will your ghost will not save you where flash would.

If you'd like an example, lets say your pushing their tower and they have someone who is low and you want to dive.  If you ghost and go for him, he will simply flash and be safe, if you have flash you have the potential to actually get an ability/attack off. Or lets say you're about to be hook by a ganking naut, his hook is about to hit you for guaranteed kill if it lands.  Ghost will not save you, flash will

The main thing is not getting caught and escaping ganks, flash will save you a lot more considerably then ghost will

Answer (score 1):

The thing about ghost and flash is: Ghost allows no mistakes. If you get caught (stunned/rooted) by an enemy when both teams are grouped mid, flash can potentially save you (cause you instantly create distance) while even if you use ghost, you still remain in their range for several more seconds.

And: Flash is surprising. If you know you can burst someone (as corki e.g.) and you use ghost, the enemy will jsut flash or use his escape abilty. if you flash and use your spell, he has nearly no time at all to react.

EDIT: You get MS as AD carry anyways (triforce/PD) so you should be able to kite/chase anyone without ghost as well.

Answer (score 0):

flash gives positioning and positioning wins fights. ghost does not offer positions and come late game when it comes down to 1 fight you will be glad you went flash.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Buckshotz, but I'd like to add that Flash is a excellent tool to escape being focused down or while trying to escape heavy cc. Also, Flash grants you the ability to jump over walls which Ghost can't offer. For ADC's Flash is definetly more viable than Ghost considering that you're really viable for your team in teamfights and Flash just helps you to position and escape in a way that Ghost does not.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes you will find that even with the escape on the ranged ad you still need that extra little jump to get away.  as chasing power it is true that ghost will let u cover more distance then flash but ghost does not let you get over walls and that and having the instant movement is what gives flash a edge on ghost.

Answer (score 0):

Ghost is superior in chases,but that is pretty much the only thing that it can be used for. Flash is way more useful in teamfights due to the nature of how AD carry is played. When in a team fight you just sit behind the main line of fire and shoot the highest priority target that comes in your range. What changes this is when a bruiser dives onto you, at this point flash is far superior due to the possibility of going over walls and being able to keep yourself out of cc range of the bruiser. The only AD carry who's gap closer isn't used in the fight is Corki. On Graves, Vayne and Exreal you need the damage that it gives you. To stay alive  you will need flash in most situations. The only time ghost is superior for a majority of champions is if you will be dominating the whole game, which you can not guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

If you are engaged on or caught out of position, Ghost most likely won't save you in as many situations as Flash would. It also lets you react to people Flashing towards you, and since you are the most important member in your team during mid-late game, the ability to be able to reposition greatly outshines the few kills a Ghost chase could provide, not to mention flash can be used offensively to great effect as well.

You could however run both Ghost and Flash, as it gives you the ability to kite, escape and chase while maintaining the "get out of jail card" that Flash brings to the table.

Answer (score 0):

This one is simple. Flash is a very strong mechanic because it immediately either removes you from a source of danger, or immediately repositions you to secure a kill. It can ignore most terrain. This is generally the strongest mechanic in the game, and this is why this spell has been nerfed for the last 3 years, over and over. I often see the kind of logic when playing low elo, it goes by the following formula: "My hero has X strong mechanic, so why would I get another of X strong mechanic?" For instance a Kassadin or Ezreal arguing that he doesnt need flash. If something is good, and you can get more of that good thing, why would you get something inferior? Ghost -could- be good situationally, but Flash is going to be better in a larger pool of scenarios. If this was something up for debate, top players who get paid to play this game would all be running flash on ad carries with blinks a long time ago. Flash is just a better mechanic.

Comment: Arguably, a certain amount of something good is good enough. If you already have a flash every 6 seconds, a second flash every 4 minutes (or w/e it is) may not _always_ be as helpful as, say Exhaust.

Answer (score 0):

The only AD carry that should even consider getting ghost is Ashe. I know aphromoo likes to take Flash/Exhaust when he plays Ashe. It helps her kite which is extremely important.